# Format an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to restructure a nested object:

**Input**

```
{
   "elements":[
      {
         "name":"catalog",
         "elements":[
            {
               "name":"book",
               "elements":[
                  {
                     "name":"author",
                     "elements":[
                        {
                           "type":"text",
                           "text":"Gambardella, Matthew"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"title",
                     "elements":[
                        {
                           "text":"XML Developers Guide"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**Desired output**

```
 {
       "children":[
          {
             "text": {"name":"catalog"},
             "children":[
                {
                   "text": {"name":"book"},
                   "children":[
                      {
                         "text": {"name":"author"},
                         "children":[
                            {
                               "type":"text",
                               "text":"Gambardella, Matthew"
                            }
                         ]
                      },
                      {
                         "text": {"name":"title"},
                         "children":[
                            {
                               "text": {"name": "XML Developers Guide"}
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                   ]
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
```

I have tried this so far

```
    function createJsonStructure(obj) {
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.elements.length; ++i) {
            console.log(obj.name);
            if(obj.elements[i].elements) {
                for (var ii = 0; ii < obj.elements[i].elements.length; ++ii) {
                    createJsonStructure(obj.elements[i].elements[ii]); 
                }
            } else {
                console.log(obj.elements[i].text);
            } 
        }
    };

   $(function(){
        createJsonStructure(xmlToJson.elements[0]);
    });
```

Comment: @trincot mistake and changed.

Comment: What is the logic to have `"text":"Gambardella, Matthew"` in your output on the one hand, and `"text": {"name": "XML Developers Guide"}` on the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this (arrow) function which uses [spread syntax in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) (ES2018):

```js
const arrange = obj => obj.elements ? {
        ..."name" in obj && { text: { name: obj.name } },
        children: obj.elements.map(arrange)
    } : {...obj};

// Sample:
const data = {"elements":[{"name":"catalog","elements":[{"name":"book","elements":[{"name":"author","elements":[{"type":"text","text":"Gambardella, Matthew"}]},{"name":"title","elements":[{"text":"XML Developers Guide"}]}]}]}]};

console.log(arrange(data));
```

If you also need to convert the existing "text" properties in the leaf-nodes (it is ambiguous in your output):

```js
const arrange = obj => ({
        ..."type" in obj && { type: obj.type },
        ..."name" in obj && { text: { name: obj.name } },
        ..."text" in obj && { text: { name: obj.text } },
        ..."elements" in obj && { children: obj.elements.map(arrange) }
    });

// Sample:
const data = {"elements":[{"name":"catalog","elements":[{"name":"book","elements":[{"name":"author","elements":[{"type":"text","text":"Gambardella, Matthew"}]},{"name":"title","elements":[{"text":"XML Developers Guide"}]}]}]}]};

console.log(arrange(data));
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I wanted.